# Copy/clone folder permissions to another folder (Windows)

Tags: windows, permissions, active-directory, copy, robocopy

I was stuck with copying the User and Group permissions from one folder to another.

The ask was - Copy one folder's permissions to another folder without copying its contents.

One solution is obvious :-

```
Get-Acl -Path $source_path | Set-Acl -Path $destination_path
```

But sometimes Set-Acl fails to copy all the group permissions and setting the correct owner.

I will attach an answer below on how I resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robocopy.

Use Robocopy with /XD and /XF tags.

Basically, /XD and /XF is used to eXclude Directories and eXclude Files.

Simply this command would work:

```
robocopy $source_folder $destination_path /copy:DATSO /secfix /e /b /MT:128 /XD "*" /XF "*"
```

If you want logs or anything,

```
robocopy $source_folder $destination_path /copy:DATSO /secfix /e /b /MT:128 /XD "*" /XF "*" /log+:$logs_path
```

Comment: Get-Acl, Set-Acl didn't work for me in creating a new place for SQL Server data files, this solution worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell:

-Open PowerShell as an administrator.
-Run the following command to get the permissions of the source folder:

```
Get-Acl -Path $source_path
```

-Save the output of the command to a variable.

```
$source_acl = Get-Acl -Path $source_path
```

-Run the following command to set the permissions of the destination folder to the same as the source folder:

```
Set-Acl -Path $destination_path -AclObject $source_acl
```

This will copy the permissions of the source folder to the destination folder, but it will not copy the contents of the source folder.

Here are some additional things to keep in mind:

-The source and destination folders must be on the same file system.

-The user running PowerShell must have the appropriate permissions to access the source and destination folders.

-If the source and destination folders have different inheritance settings, the permissions of the destination folder may not be what you expect.

On the other hand, Here are some of the most popular third-party tools to help you directly to copy one folder's permissions to another folder without copying its contents, check FastCopy, Gs Richcopy360, and Syncback.

I hope this helps!